# Export images in HTML web view as pdf in iOS using Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, export-to-pdf

I have a `UIWebView` with HTML table template content. It has a column with images which are loaded from documents directory in the iPhone device.

The problem is that when I export the html content to pdf, the images are not shown at all and an empty cell is shown instead.

I use `UIPrintPageRenderer` with `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` to export html to pdf.

Is there any way to fix this?